# Overriding the always-top property of the navigation bar in Titanium

Tags: iphone, navigation, titanium, overriding

In Titanium for iPhone is it possible to display something above the navigation bar – or just disabling the always-top property of the navigation bar?

***This is how it looks right now***:
[image: The actual state of the app]

***This is part of the actual Photoshop-mock-up***:
[image: Photoshop-Mockup]

The code-snippet invoking this is:

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title: 'Home',
        navBarHidden: false,
        barImage: 'topbar.png',
        backgroundImage: 'bga.png'
});
c = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image: 'logobar.png',
        top: -13,
        right: 7,
        width: 74,
        height: 108,
        exitOnClose: !0
})
try {
        win1.add(c);
        c.animate({zIndex:3});
        win1.addEventListener('focus', function () {
                Titanium.App.Analytics.trackPageview('/win1')
        });
}catch(e){
        alert(e);
}
```

The try-catch was implemented as I didn't trust the existence of .animate, however it did exist but did not work.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer(, or maybe not what it should be like)**

Titanium itself does not support the feature of manipulating the zIndex or rather the onTop-properties. However, I've found a workaround allowing the overlay to be shown.

[image: Screenshot: How it'll look like]

This workaround works by the way Titanium handles windows. First, we define the main window (e.g. win1) and fill it. Then we create an assistant window (e.g. win1a) and assign the ImageView to it. Then we position the new window on top of the other window and voilà.

```
    var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            title: "*******",
            navBarHidden: false,
            barImage: 'topbar.png',
            backgroundColor: "gray",
    });
    var win1l = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            title: "",
            navBarHidden: true,
            height: 84,
            width: 64,
            right: 0,
            top: 0
    });
// Inject ImageView into top-most window
    win1l.add(Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            image: "logobar.png",
            top: 2,
            right: 5,
            width: 60.3, //74, // 74/108 = 0.6851851852
            height: 88, //108, // ((108-20)*(74/108)) = 60.29629 ~ 60.3
            exitOnClose: !0
    }));
    win1l.open();
```

I hope this might have been helpful for you.

Thanks, -Kenan.

Comment: i don't need this, but it's a pretty smart solution